# Dimension of eigenspaces w/o multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is it possible to show that the sum of the dimensions of all eigenspaces of an n x n matrix cannot be greater than n (in other words, that you cannot find more than n linearly independent eigenvectors), without using the fact that the geometric multiplicity is less than or equal to the algebraic multiplicity?

My text book of algebra indirectly implied this (in explaining how to confirm that a matrix is diagonizable) before introducing the theorem of geometric and algebraic multiplicity. Is there some obvious reason I don't see?

Answer (score 2):

In $\mathbb R^n$ you can't have more than $n$ independent vectors (eigen or not) so certainly you can't have more than $n$ independent eigenvectors of any $n\times n$ matrix. This follows immediately by showing that the dimension of $\mathbb R^n$ is $n$, a fact that does not involve any consideration of algebraic or geometric multiplicity of anything.

Comment: You should add that eigenvectors to different eigenvalues are linearly independent.

Comment: So how do you know that the independent eigenvectors of the matrix can not be in some higher dimension than R^n (which is actually the same as my original question)?

Comment: Since by definition an eigenvalue of an $n \times n $ matrix lives in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 1):

If we denote $E_{\lambda}$ the eigenspace of the eigenvalue $\lambda$, and since $$E_{\lambda_i}\cap E_{\lambda_j}=\{0\}$$ for different eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$ we then find $$\dim(\oplus_iE_{\lambda_i})=\sum_i\dim E_{\lambda_i}\leq n$$